# How can I select records, based on if another record doesn't exist?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select certain records, based on if records matching a field don't exist. I have the following table:

```
ID    Name    Fruit
--------------------
1     Steve   Apple
2     Steve   Orange
3     Bob     Apple
4     Gary    Apple
5     Gary    Orange
6     Paul    Apple
7     Jeff    Orange
```

Expected results are to only show records where someone has an orange, but they don't have an apple - in this scenario, just Jeff's record should be shown.

Struggling to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Homework, and you want us to do it for you?!? If we do, you wont learn much.

Comment: Pls. add your DB name like SQL SERVER,ORACLE,MYSQL etc

Answer (score 1):

You could do a WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT t1.Name 
FROM your_table t1
WHERE fruit = 'Orange' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM your_table t2 
WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name 
AND fruit = 'Apple'
)
```

This is looking for orange records first, then excluding any records for the same person who also has apple.

If using SQL Server, you can use EXCEPT

```
SELECT name 
FROM @your_table t1
WHERE fruit = 'Orange' 

EXCEPT 

SELECT name 
FROM @your_table t1
WHERE fruit = 'apple'
```

This finds all the orange people, and then removes anyone who also has apple from the data set.

Answer (score 1):

You can count fruits per user and select users with just 1 orange fruit. If there is no warranty, that every user can have one fruit per type, use `count(distinct fruit)` instead of `count(fruit)`

```
Select Name
From tbl
Group by Name
Having Count(Fruit)=1 
and max(Fruit)='Orange'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to like aggregation for this purpose.  In this case:

```
select Name
from tbl
where fruit in ('Orange', 'Apple')
group by Name
having min(Fruit) = 'Orange' and min(fruit) = max(fruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereYou can try the below query to meet your expectation.

```
select Name
from tbl
group by Name
having Min(Fruit) = 'Orange'
```